# Java Twitter4j OAuth not working

Tags: java, oauth, twitter4j

I am reading [these](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html) Twitter4j examples. I am trying to get #7: OAuth support to work but I am having troubles. I have the following code:

```
try {
    Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer("VALID KEY FROM APP HERE", "VALID SECRET FROM APP HERE");
    RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
    AccessToken accessToken = null;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while(null == accessToken) {
        System.out.println("Open the following URL and grant access to your account:");
        System.out.println(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
        System.out.print("Enter the PIN(if aviailable) or just hit enter.[PIN]:");
        String pin = br.readLine();
        if(pin.length() > 0){
            accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, pin);
        } else {
            accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(twitter.verifyCredentials().getId());
    System.out.println(accessToken);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output in my console is the following:

```
Open the following URL and grant access to your account:
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=<REMOVED>
Enter the PIN(if aviailable) or just hit enter.[PIN]:
```

When I copy the original link and go to the URL in my web browser it opens the expected Twitter app authorization page. When I grant it access it sends me to the app's callback (doesn't exist) as expected. I am never given a pin as described in my console, so I just press enter and the result is:

```
401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were 
missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
Error processing your OAuth request: Invalid oauth_verifier parameter

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
        http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=17bf128c or
        http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=12b8f614
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[17bf128c-12b8f614], statusCode=401, message=null
, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.4}
        at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:164)
        at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:57)
        at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.post(HttpClientBase.java:86)
        at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthAccessToken(OAuthAuthorizat
ion.java:125)
        at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthAccessToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:33
6)
        at tweetserver.TweetServer.main(TweetServer.java:51)
```

I have checked my app's key and secret multiple times and copy/pasted them into my code. I have also used the same key/secret in a PHP application & in Twitter4j with the access token and the access token secret (allows direct access to use the API on my account without needing permission) without any problems.

I believe I am not understanding the example clearly, how could I fix this problem? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have customised this line with your own credentials?

```
twitter.setOAuthConsumer("VALID KEY FROM APP HERE", "VALID SECRET FROM APP HERE");
```